# How to set up cabal for ghc 7.10 on windows 64-bit

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have just downloaded the newest GHC 7.10.1 version, and I am trying to set up the cabal system to make it work. But I couldn't find the 64-bit `cabal` binary for 64 bit windows.

Haskell Platform does not have 7.10 yet. So I went to https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html , but there is only binary for 32-bit windows. I tried to use that version to `cabal update`, but `cabal.exe` just crashed while setting up the initial config.

I was wondering what's the procedure to set up `cabal` for 64-bit GHC?

Comment: Did you try [MinGHC](https://github.com/fpco/minghc) instead?

Comment: @Zeta. I haven't. It looks like what I needed. Do you know if I can installed it without the MSys part? I have mine own msys with lots of stuff built in in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

I used a previous version of 64-bit GHC, such as those in Haskell Platform, to compile a `cabal.exe`, and use it to do:

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

(boot-strapping).

After this, the `cabal.exe` installed into the local cabal directory was 64-bit and worked just fine.

Note: I have tried MinGHC 64-bit as @Zeta hinted, but the `cabal.exe` there was also 32-bit. It seems to be incompatible with the 64-bit GHC system, and gave me crashes just as the 32-bit `cabal.exe` downloaded from the official website.